# How to Adding values of two dimnetional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the below given array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2,3   
    [1] => 2,3   
)
```

I want to sum up and get result in a variable.  E.g. variable `a = 4 (2+2=4)` and variable `b = 6 (3+3=6)`.  I am coding in php.

Comment: i'm sorry but if you can't make an attempt at doing this then should you even be working with php? Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use EXPLODE inside foreach**

```
<?php
$yourArr = array('2,3','2,3');
$a = 0;
$b =0;
foreach ($yourArr as $temp)
{
    $tempnew = explode(",",$temp);

    $a += $tempnew[0];
    $b += $tempnew[1];
}
echo "a = ".$a."<br>";
echo "b = ".$b;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$a = 0;
$b =0;
foreach ($yourArr as $temp)
{
    $a += $temp[0];
    $b += $temp[1];
}
echo "a = ".$a."<br>";
echo "b = ".$b;
```

**Output**

```
a = 4
b = 6
```

Comment: I am getting value of a as 4 but b is showing 0.

Comment: What you tried can you give example in question?

Comment: When i try the above code i get Array
(
    [0] => 2,3   
    [1] => 2,3   
)

a = 4
b = 0

Comment: you have to use explode inside foreach  as code below..